# problem with flexbox, align-self does not work

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I don't understand what im doing wrong with the use of flexbox.

**I'd like to have my button on the extreme right of the screen (but that does not happen) and the text input on the left.**
I'd like to do it using flexbox. here is the code:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  background: red;
}

button {
  align-self: flex-end;
  }
```

```html
<div class="adder-comp">
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="aggiungi compito.." />
    <button>crea</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: it works, give an height to the form and see it standing at bottom. align-self is for the vertical placement

Comment: Your `main-axis` is `row`. align-self works instead on the `cross-axis`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use  `justify-content: space-between;` on the parent instead:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="adder-comp">
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="aggiungi compito.." />
    <button>crea</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use `margin-left: auto` on the button:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  background: red;
}

button {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="adder-comp">
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="aggiungi compito.." />
    <button>crea</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be looking `align-content` vs `align-self` and `justify-content` in `form` tag.

```
<div class="adder-comp">
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="aggiungi compito.." />
    <button>crea</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
  background: red;
}

button {
  align-content: flex-end;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
form{
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  justify-content: space-between
}
```

Just add justify-content: space-between to the form